# How to modify the network bandwidth, latency and inducing packet loss for an outgoing traffic from windows laptop

Tags: networking

I want to simulate network issues to test against bad network condition from a windows laptop. Basically I am planning to modify the network bandwidth, latency and induce packet loss. I will be connecting a video streaming device to my windows laptop using LAN cable and will be be feeding this modified network and want to see the issues there. I was earlier using Shunra for the same, but it is currently not available

Comment: none of those things are actually "things"; they are all emergent characteristics of a connection at a particular point in space/time. you would need sophisticated low-level software (like drivers or kernel modules) in order to fake those characteristics. I don't have any ideas for you, and we don't do software recommendations on this site.

Comment: @FrankThomas Apple's OSes, the other BSDs, and Linux all have built-in tools for this, so this wouldn't be a software-rec question on those platforms. Does Microsoft not provide any kind of network link conditioner functionality built into Windows?

Comment: I've been a windows admin going back to 3.11, and while it is up to the audience to judge how good I might or might not be at it (I've certainly slipped over the years as I turned to development and architecture), I can assure you that I have never heard of a windows utility designed to instill a lack of stableness in an application arbitrarily, regarding the network or otherwise.  If I may ask, what is the most common linux util used for generating artificial packet loss or latency?

Comment: @frank thomas, sounds like we may be exact opposites. I'm a Linux guy, but I have definitely seen network techs doing exactly this on windows in the data centers I frequent. No idea what the software was they were using though. In Linux you can use **netem & tc** commands to do exactly what the op is asking. (Linux 2.6 and above)

Comment: https://programmer.ink/think/using-tc-to-simulate-network-latency-and-packet-loss-under-linux.html